# Binding multiple User Controls to single collection

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

Scenario:

[image]

There are three things: UserControls, GridView and a Collection. There is 1:1:1 Mapping between UserControl:Grid Row: Collection Row

The problem is how to bind a single usercontrol to a collection row. So if any object in collection is updated, corresponding GridView row and usercontrol should be updated automatically.

EDIT: The complete UI would is multithreaded. So most of the times the original collection as a whole would never be recreated. Only objects would be added/deleted/updated.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is rebind all controls on the event handler for the collection update.

Comment: UI is multithreaded, there might be 100's of updates very couple of seconds. This would just kill the performance.

Comment: Ok. So you can "mark" the collection as dirty, and handel it however you want in the different controls. Maybe rebind only when something is done on one of the controls. Much like what this site does when you reply to a question and while you are replying, another answer is posted.